# How to plot two lines on a same plot, from a single data table/ data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I have such data table structure, and I am so struggle how could I plot two line to clearly indicate two condition:

```
> Dependent   Counts     Indication
> 0           2          Stay   
> 1           4          Stay 
> 2           1          Stay
> 0           11         Left 
> 1           5          Left 
> 2           3          Left  
> 3           2          Left   
> 4           1          Left
```

[Btw]
I saw some reference/ question asked and solution provided
Dual line on single plot could definitely achievable by:

```
x <- c(...)
y1 <- c(...)
y2 <- c(...)
```

But this kind of solution did not hit my needs. I am seeking another way to do this as my table is prepared in the above-mentioned form.

Comment: Maybe I did not make it clear, but I wish to have x-axis(Dependent), y-axis(Counts) and I will have two lines each for either "Stay" or "Left" condition.

Comment: Thanks @maRtin for helping me to organize the table in a more readable form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with ggplot

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Dependent, y=Counts, group=Indication, color=Indication)) + geom_line()
```

Comment: Hi Sandipan, thanks for responding to my question. But maybe I did not make it clear, I wish to have x-axis(Dependent), y-axis(counts) and I will have two lines each for either "Stay" or "Left" condition.

Comment: @Chun I see, updated the above code as per your requirement.

Comment: Hi Sandipan, wow it works and the code itself is very clear! Thousand thanks! I really learnt something :)

Answer (score 1):

if `df` is your dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame("Dependent"=c(0,1,2,0,1,2,3,4),
                 "Counts"=c(2,4,1,11,5,3,2,1),
                 "Indication"=c("Stay","Stay","Stay","Left","Left","Left","Left","Left"))

library(tidyr)
df_tidy <- spread(df, Indication, Counts)

plot(df_tidy$Dependent, df_tidy$Left, type="l")
lines(df_tidy$Dependent, df_tidy$Stay, col="red")
```

I am first using `tidyr` to "spread" your dataframe and from there you can use the standard plot function.

**Spread:**

> *This function takes data that is in a key-value format and returns a*
> *rectangular tidy cell format.* *As you can see spread() restructures the dataframe by removing redundant rows without losing any information.*

For more information on `spread` and `tidyr`, please look [here](http://www.gis-blog.com/data-management-with-r-tidyr-part-1/).

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for responding to my question. But maybe I did not make it clear, I wish to have x-axis(Dependent), y-axis(counts) and I will have two lines each for either "Stay" or "Left" condition.

Comment: thousand thanks! I visited your website and I felt your tidyr is a pretty cool feature! :)

btw, I ran the code and the output plot is not exactly what I want still.

finally I worked out the exact solution I am looking for anyway:
ggplot() + 
geom_line(aes(subset(dataStay_Left$Dependents, dataStay_Left$ind=="Stay"), subset(dataStay_Left$Counts, dataStay_Left$ind=="Stay"), group=1)) + 
geom_line(aes(subset(dataStay_Left$Dependents, dataStay_Left$ind=="Left"), subset(dataStay_Left$Counts, dataStay_Left$ind=="Left"), group=2))

The way the code is written might be messy though. :P

Answer (score 0):

Finally I worked out the exact answer I am looking for.

```
ggplot() + geom_line(aes(subset(dataStay_Left$Dependents,
dataStay_Left$ind=="Stay"), subset(dataStay_Left$Counts, 
dataStay_Left$ind=="Stay"), group=1)) + 
geom_line(aes(subset(dataStay_Left$Dependents, dataStay_Left$ind=="Left"), 
subset(dataStay_Left$Counts, dataStay_Left$ind=="Left"), group=2))
```

Thanks for the help provided and the discussion.